# Update 2 items in state from separate API calls concurrently

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

How can I update two values in a state (adjustedNetWorth and adjustedLiquidAssets) from 2 separate API calls. The issue I'm having is that CombinedNWLADetails state is being overwritten since state updates don't run in order.

```
 const getAdjustedNetWorth = (nwla: ICombinedNWLA) => {
    onCommonGet({
      url: nwlaUrl.calculateAdjustedNetWorth(
        nwla.combinedNetWorth,
        nwla.lessEquity,
        nwla.uncalledCapitalCommitments,
        nwla.calculationOptionId
      ),
      successCallback: (data: number) => {
        console.log('Adjusted Net Worth: ' + data);
        setCombinedNWLADetails({
          ...nwla,
          adjustedNetWorth: data
      })
      },
      recordType: 'Adjusted Net Worth'
    })
  };

  const getAdjustedLiquidAssets = (nwla: ICombinedNWLA) => {
    onCommonGet({
      url: nwlaUrl.calculateAdjustedLiquidAssets(
        nwla.combinedLiquidAssets,
        nwla.lessEquity,
        nwla.uncalledCapitalCommitments,
        nwla.calculationOptionId
      ),
      successCallback: (data: number) => {
        console.log('Adjusted Liquid Assets: ' + data);
        setCombinedNWLADetails({
          ...nwla,
          adjustedLiquidAssets: data
      })
      },
      recordType: 'Adjusted Liquid Assets'
    })
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want to make multiple state changes that might occur concurrently, you should use [updater functions](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state). React would queue the updates, and each update would be called with the state produces by it's predecessor.

Example:

```
setCombinedNWLADetails(prevNwla => ({
  ...prevNwla,
  adjustedNetWorth: data
}))

setCombinedNWLADetails(prevNwla => ({
  ...prevNwla,
  adjustedLiquidAssets: data
}))
```